# how to calculate the inliers points from my rotation and translation matrix?

Tags: c++, opencv, rotation, opencv-solvepnp

In estimate the camera pose using **cv::solvePnPRansac**, the input are **objectPoints** and **imagePoints**. And the output are the rotation and translation matrix, plus  number of  ***inliers*** points

I make to use GA “Gigantic algorithm” to generate a new rotation and translation matrix. What I like to calculate number of  inliers points using my new  rotation and translation.

If I have the points lists
*std::vector objectPoints;*
*std::vector imagePoints;*
and the cameraMatrix and distCoeffs
and I have the rotation and translation matrix, how can I calculate the **inliers** points?
I know that cv::solvePnPRansac will calculate the inliers, rotation and translation from the two points list, but I need to calculate the inliers from my rotation and translation?

Thanks for your support

Comment: Unclear. Could you edit your question and give some context. What data hold `opoints` and `ipoints` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and will test it and update my answer from the [OpenCV](http://answers.opencv.org/question/138651/how-to-calculate-the-inliers-points-from-my-rotation-and-translation-matrix/?comment=138750#comment-138750)